# wrong X509IssuerName, wrong X509SerialNumber error in Zatca XML validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, xml-validation, .net-4.7.2

I'm working KSA Zatca eInvoicing phase 2 integration. I'm using SDKNETFrameWorkLib for sigining Invoice xmls. But when I try with Standard Invoices XML it was validating on https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/TestXML site. but if I try with Simplified Invoice XML it is always showing wrong X509IssuerName and wrong X509SerialNumber. My certificate was generated for both Standard Invoices and Simplified Invoices. Can someone help me on this? thanks in advance.

I have tried with diff certificates and I have tried different application but all are having the same issue.

Comment: Hi I am facing  the same issue. Were you able to solve this ?